# Speed up rolling window in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this code which works fine and gives me the result I am looking for. It loops through a list of window sizes to create rolling aggregates for each metric in the sum_metric_list, min_metric_list and max_metric_list.

```
# create the rolling aggregations for each window
for window in constants.AGGREGATION_WINDOW:
    # get the sum and count sums
    sum_metrics_names_list = [x[6:] + "_1_" + str(window) for x in sum_metrics_list]
    adt_df[sum_metrics_names_list] = adt_df.groupby('athlete_id')[sum_metrics_list].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = window, min_periods = 1).sum())

    # get the min of mins
    min_metrics_names_list = [x[6:] + "_1_" + str(window) for x in min_metrics_list]
    adt_df[min_metrics_names_list] = adt_df.groupby('athlete_id')[min_metrics_list].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = window, min_periods = 1).min())

    # get the max of max
    max_metrics_names_list = [x[6:] + "_1_" + str(window) for x in max_metrics_list]
    adt_df[max_metrics_names_list] = adt_df.groupby('athlete_id')[max_metrics_list].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = window, min_periods = 1).max())
```

It works well on small datasets but as soon as I run it on my full data with >3000 metrics and 40 windows it becomes very slow. Is there any way to optimise this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The benchmark (and code) below suggests that you can save a significant amount of time by using

```
df.groupby(...).rolling()
```

instead of

```
df.groupby(...)[col].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(...))
```

The main time-saving idea here is to try to apply vectorized functions (such as `sum`) to the largest possible array (or DataFrame) at one time (with one function call) instead of many tiny function calls.

`df.groupby(...).rolling().sum()` calls `sum` on each (grouped) sub-DataFrame. It 
can compute the rolling sums for *all the columns* with one call.
You could use `df[sum_metrics_list+[key]].groupby(key).rolling().sum()` to compute the rolling/sum on the `sum_metrics_list` columns.

In contrast, `df.groupby(...)[col].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(...))` calls `sum` on a *single column* of each (grouped) sub-DataFrame. Since you have >3000 metrics you end up calling  `df.groupby(...)[col].rolling().sum()` (or `min` or `max`) 3000 times.

Of course, this pseudo-logic of counting the number of calls is only a heuristic which *may* guide you in the direction of faster code. The proof is in the pudding:

```
import collections
import timeit 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_df(nrows=100, ncols=3):
    seed = 2018
    np.random.seed(seed)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(nrows, ncols)))
    df['athlete_id'] = np.random.randint(10, size=nrows)
    return df

def orig(df, key='athlete_id'):
    columns = list(df.columns.difference([key]))
    result = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    for window in range(2, 4):
        for col in columns:
            colname = 'sum_col{}_winsize{}'.format(col, window)
            result[colname] = df.groupby(key)[col].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(
                center=False, window=window, min_periods=1).sum())
            colname = 'min_col{}_winsize{}'.format(col, window)
            result[colname] = df.groupby(key)[col].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(
                center=False, window=window, min_periods=1).min())
            colname = 'max_col{}_winsize{}'.format(col, window)
            result[colname] = df.groupby(key)[col].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(
                center=False, window=window, min_periods=1).max())
    result = pd.concat([df, result], axis=1)
    return result

def alt(df, key='athlete_id'):
    """
    Call rolling on the whole DataFrame, not each column separately
    """
    columns = list(df.columns.difference([key]))
    result = [df]
    for window in range(2, 4):
        rolled = df.groupby(key, group_keys=False).rolling(
            center=False, window=window, min_periods=1)

        new_df = rolled.sum().drop(key, axis=1)
        new_df.columns = ['sum_col{}_winsize{}'.format(col, window) for col in columns]
        result.append(new_df)

        new_df = rolled.min().drop(key, axis=1)
        new_df.columns = ['min_col{}_winsize{}'.format(col, window) for col in columns]
        result.append(new_df)

        new_df = rolled.max().drop(key, axis=1)
        new_df.columns = ['max_col{}_winsize{}'.format(col, window) for col in columns]
        result.append(new_df)

    df = pd.concat(result, axis=1)
    return df

timing = collections.defaultdict(list)
ncols = [3, 10, 20, 50, 100]
for n in ncols:
    df = make_df(ncols=n)
    timing['orig'].append(timeit.timeit(
        'orig(df)',
        'from __main__ import orig, alt, df',
        number=10))
    timing['alt'].append(timeit.timeit(
        'alt(df)',
        'from __main__ import orig, alt, df',
        number=10))

plt.plot(ncols, timing['orig'], label='using groupby/apply (orig)')
plt.plot(ncols, timing['alt'], label='using groupby/rolling (alternative)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('number of columns')
plt.ylabel('seconds')
print(pd.DataFrame(timing, index=pd.Series(ncols, name='ncols')))
plt.show()
```

[image]
and yields these `timeit` benchmarks

```
            alt       orig
ncols                     
3      0.871695   0.996862
10     0.991617   3.307021
20     1.168522   6.602289
50     1.676441  16.558673
100    2.521121  33.261957
```

The speed advantage of `alt` compared to `orig` seems to increase as the number of columns increases.